# As transiting passenger, how to go from T2 to T3 in Dubai airport?

Tags: air-travel, transit, international-travel, airport-transfer

From CCU we will be arriving at Dubai T2 at 05:55 on Flydubai and thereafter will be transiting for Seattle on Emirates departing from T3 at 09:55.(All in one single ticket)

How we may reach T3 from T2? Are we required to re-checkin in Dubai for our onward journey?

Comment: Is this on one ticket or did you book the flights separately.

Comment: It is on single ticket.

Comment: To actually get there, Dubai airport has a pretty extensive tram network.

Comment: @user25730 T2 is the odd one out, it's the LCC terminal and not directly connected to the rest.